# Slice image URL to a physical tree folders with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am not sure about the terms of my question, but I have image URLS built like this :

```
$finalUrl = '/images/' . base64($url) . '.jpg';
```

The $finalUrl goes to an intern screenshot generation service (with NodeJS), which decode the base64 encoded $url to take the page screenshot then save the JPG in a physical folder.

I use Nginx as a HTTP proxy to serve the cached JPG if it exists or forward to the NodeJS server to take the screenshot.

It works fine but, my cache folder has more than 400 000 JPGs now! So I would like to have my cached JPG path like this :

```
/cache/screenshot/{part1}/{part2}/{part3}/{part4}.jpg
```

A tree structure in order to have no more than 10 000 files per folder. No problem for NodeJS to write to a such path, but how can I tell to Nginx to look the cached JPG in it?

Comment: how exactly are u going to split the name to 4 parts?

Comment: I could split the URL , part1 = substr(base64($url), 0, X), part2 = substr(base64($url), X, X) and so on